# Need to change a value within a function for each row in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets

```
=ArrayFormula(row(1:100))
```

fills 100 columns with numbers 1-100.

=ImportJSON("http://www.domain.com/sample1.json", "")

inserts my JSON data keys and values into corresponding rows.

How can I set this up so that for each column, I change the number for the JSON file?

I tried combining these two functions but it just errors.
    =ArrayFormula(ImportJSON("http://www.domain.com/sample&row(1:100)&.json", ""))

Now this works:

```
=ArrayFormula(row(1:100)&ImportJSON("http://www.domain.com/sample1.json", ""))
```

but it's not putting the number in the desired spot. It's just adding it before each cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to separate the first part of the url, the formula and the second part with quotations, deeming them as strings, note there are quotes around "http://www.domain.com/sample"  then a function insertion then the rest of the string ".json"

```
=arrayformula("http://www.domain.com/sample"&row(1:100)&".json")
```

Comment: You got me thinking on the right track. It does still pose a problem when trying to use the ImportJSON function (which I found on GitHub) within the ArrayFormula function. I tried a few different things and finally came up with this: `=ImportJSON("http://www.domain.com/sample"&row()-1&".json")` This uses the number of the row to fill in the information in the ImportJSON function.

Comment: Good I'm glad you came to that, that was originally what I had done, I just modified my answer  to support your range of rows :) but I was having an issue with the arrayformula for the import part as well